# Crear array en php dentro de un while

Tags: php, array

Hola tengo una consulta sql, la cual después realizo un while, el resultado de la consulta son números, por ej 13 y 15, y quiero que me guarde los valores en un array tipo [13, 15], pero al hacer echo del array fuera del while solo me muestra el ultimo numero que seria el 15, dejo el codigo por si alguno me ayuda, gracias.

```
mysql_query("SELECT ip.id_impuesto
        FROM imp_prod AS ip
        INNER JOIN impuesto AS im ON im.id_impuesto = ip.id_impuesto
        WHERE ip.CODPROD = {$id_producto} 
        AND im.en_pesos = 1");

while ($imp_otros = mysql_fetch_array($query_otros)) {
    $array_int = array($imp_otros["id_impuesto"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque siempre estas asignando el último valor a $array_int, tienes que declarar esa variable fuera del bucle y luego asignar los valores a su último indice.

```
$array_int = [];

while ($imp_otros = mysql_fetch_array($query_otros)) {
    $array_int[] = $imp_otros["id_impuesto"];
}
```